# Google Cloud Print Fails - Finding Logs?

Tags: windows-server-2012, printing, google, print-server, shared-printers

Recently we've been seeing Google Cloud Print Service fail to print on Xerox printers.
We're relatively sure it's a Drivers issue.
When attempting to Print to a Xerox printer, the Cloud Print portal will report a failed job while all future attempts to print to ANY cloud print printer associated with the service will fail until the Cloud Print service is restarted.

The Cloud Print service continues to report as "Running".

While Cloud Print provides the logging below, more information would be better.

Where Can I Get better information on the details of Cloud Connects failure to print?

Xerox Driver info:
Xerox Phaser 6128 Version: 2.6.16.0
[image: Driver Screenshot]

Relevant Logging below:

`[5440:7116:0217/185425:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(509)] CP_CONNECTOR: Starting printing, printer id: 3d46ee36-0529-828d-ad90-a326bbd8bd91
[5440:2212:0217/185425:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(260)] CP_CONNECTOR: Job failed (spool failed)
[5440:7116:0217/185425:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(590)] CP_CONNECTOR: Job failed, printer id: 3d46ee36-0529-828d-ad90-a326bbd8bd91, job id: d2acc44c-ca1a-377f-f6cc-8cf798ca7abc, error: 3
[5440:7116:0217/185425:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(539)] CP_CONNECTOR: Updating job status, printer id: 3d46ee36-0529-828d-ad90-a326bbd8bd91, job id: d2acc44c-ca1a-377f-f6cc-8cf798ca7abc, job status: 2
[5440:7116:0217/185426:VERBOSE1:cloud_print_url_fetcher.cc(168)] CP_PROXY: OnURLFetchComplete, url: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/control?jobid=d2acc44c-ca1a-377f-f6cc-8cf798ca7abc&status=ERROR&connector_code=3, response code: 200
[5440:7116:0217/185426:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(432)] CP_CONNECTOR: Handling failure status update response, printer id: 3d46ee36-0529-828d-ad90-a326bbd8bd91
[5440:7116:0217/185426:VERBOSE1:printer_job_handler.cc(495)] CP_CONNECTOR: Stopping printer job handler, printer id: 3d46ee36-0529-828d-ad90-a326bbd8bd91`

Comment: "When in doubt, run process monitor" http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2011/07/18/3439288.aspx

Comment: If you're using Windows XP, make sure you also have the Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3) installed. Also check this guide below https://support.google.com/cloudprint/faq/2541828?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to use the alternate PS package instead of the existing PCL6 iteration?

Judging by your screen shot, you're currently using the PCL6 V3 print driver made for windows 8/8.1 [found here](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-6505/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=win8x64&fileLanguage=en/%22Xerox%206505%20Drivers%22) and depending on your environment you may want to be using the PS package.

Depending on how your environment is set up, this may or may not apply. Are you all using one version of windows? Is it a heterogeneous network? Do you have any other Xerox drivers installed not shown on your screen shot?

Before installing the PS driver, I would advise you remove the existing iteration of the same model's package and then reassign the print queue to the newly loaded driver. See if this causes in ANY changes in behavior as that will allow us to pinpoint the problem more specifically. Additionally, this particular model doesn't seem to be compatible with the Google Cloud system, but I would advise you to attempt the PS driver as a possible troubleshooting step into potentially reaching a permanent solution.

[Google Cloud Print > Compatible Products](http://www.office.xerox.com/software-solutions/google-cloud-print/enus.html)

Comment: Your answer matches closely to the solution I ultimately went with.  Thanks for leaving some breadcrumbs for the next person to find.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm glad you were able to resolve it. 

For anyone else having similar issues, you should definitely attempt the alternate version of the package you're attempting to use; but before doing so I urge purging the previously existing package iteration completely from the server/environment.

Once the Xerox drivers have been removed, installing the alternate package should give some light as to what the problem is. Another note: the PS package will not work appropriately on devices who do not have the post script option installed.